# How to increase coverage in unit testing using Karma, Jasmine & Angular?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a module for which coverage is not increasing.
I tried various expects & assertions but still

```
this.getSomeParams = function () {
  var a = '';
  if(access.hasB()) {
    a += 'B';
  }
  if(access.hasC()) {
    a += 'C';
  }
  a = a || 'A';
  return {
    key1:'val1',
    a: a,
    tax: 20
  };
};
```

there is no coverage for the mentioned code.My Unit test for the above code is as below. I have tested the response to be true or false for multiple conditions also, checked that service function is returning expected response or not. the test cases are running successful. However, the coverage is not increasing.

```
it('should test a to be B if access.hasB returns true', function(){
      function testgetSomeParams(){
        a = '';
        expect(access.hasB).toBeTruthy();
        expect(access.hasC).toBeFalsy();
        expect(a).toBeDefined();
        expect(a).toMatch('B');
      }
    });
   it('should test a to be C if access.hasC returns true', function(){
      function testgetSomeParams(){
        a += 'C';
        expect(access.hasB).toBeFalsy();
        expect(access.hasC).toBeTruthy();
        expect(a).toMatch('C');
      }
    });
    it('should test a to be A if access.hasB & access.hasC are false', function(){
      function errorgetSomeParams(){
        a = '';
        a = a || 'A';
        expect(access.hasB).toBeFalsy();
        expect(access.hasC).toBeFalsy();
        expect(a).toBeDefined();
        expect(a).toMatch('A');
      }
    });

     it('should return a promise for update', function () {
       var fetchDefer = $q.defer();
        spyOn(someGeekySrv, 'getSomeParams').andCallFake(function () {
          return d1.promise;
        });
        fetchDefer.resolve([{
        key1:'val1',
        a: 'A',
        tax: 20
      }]);
        someGeekySrv.getSomeParams().then(function (data,status) {
               expect(data.a).toMatch('A');
               expect(data.success).toBeTruthy();
        });
        $rootScope.$digest();
      });
```

defination of access is:

```
 access= {
          hasB: function(){
            return sessionStorage.getItem('abc');
            },
          hasC: function(){
            return sessionStorage.getItem('xyz');
            }
          };
```

Comment: u means value of 'a' inside  getSomeParams not updating

Comment: Please show defination of access